# How to validate a search form in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, post, blogs, message

I have implemented a simple search functionality for my rails 3 blog application. I want to validate it, in such a way, that with non-matching keywords, or when the search text field is blank, & when user clicks search button, it should display a message saying "your search criteria is invalid. Please try using valid keywords"

My Code is as follows :

In Post Model,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :body
validates_presence_of :search
validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :body, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where("title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?","%#{search.strip}%","%#{search.strip}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

In Post Controller,

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index    
   @posts=Post.includes(:comments).search(params[:search])
   .paginate(per_page:2,page:params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

In Posts/index.html.erb (Views)

```
<div class = "search">
 <span>
  <%= form_tag(posts_path, :method => :get, :validate => true) do %>
    <p>
    <%= text_field_tag (:search), params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
  </br>
    <% if params[:search].blank? %>
    <%= flash[:error] = "Sorry... Your Search criteria didnt match. 
     Please try using  different keyword." %>
    <% else %>
    </p>
  <% end %>  
  </p>
  <% end %>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but not working. Can anyone please help me achieve my objective. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ActiveModel for a tableless model with validations - maybe a model like `PostSearch`, on which you could add validations like you would for any other model.

the model:

```
class PostSearch
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :input

  validates_presence_of :input
  validates_length_of :input, :maximum => 500

end
```

and your form:

```
<%= form_for PostSearch.new(), :url=>posts_path, :method=>:get, :validate=>true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :input %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :input %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Search" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Pair it with [client side validations gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) a good user experience.

Info on ActiveModel:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Railscast source code:

https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-219/

Answer (score 2):

You can check if params[:search] is blank or not, means if text field is blank:

```
if params[:search].blank?
   flash[:notice] = "your search criteria is invalid. Please try using valid keywords"
   render 'index'
end
```

Edited:

If there are no keyword match:

```
if @posts.nil?
  flash[:notice] = "your search criteria is invalid. Please try using valid keywords"
  render 'index'
end
```

Comment: what about non-matching keywords ? Like if he enters some garbage input on search text field for ex :- dfkvjsdgndfk    then it should also return the same error message